# Emergency Visa to US for accompanying son (for his intern)

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I am visiting US for a intern in summer. My father wants to join me, so he had applied for visa but got denied (It was written that he coouldn't convince them that he would return to India).

Can he now apply for an emergency visa? How long does it take to get an emergency visa? My intern starts on 19th this month.

Comment: Forget about it. There’s nothing like that for his circumstance.

Comment: In a [now-deleted near copy of this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137903/visa-for-urgent-medical-attendence) the OP states: "I have fallen sick, and would like my father to join me."

Comment: That would still not be an emergency,

Comment: suppose I am seriously injured and many broken bones, and the company would highly benefit from my availability. Under such a hypothetical scenario, is it now an emergency that a family member can accompany me?

Comment: Are you going to dream up ever more extreme hypothetical scenarios until someone here says 'yes'? What's the point?

Answer (score 6):

No. Emergency visa appointments are for "urgent medical or humanitarian need to travel" (source: [US Embassy in the UK](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/emergency-appointments/)). Your father has no such need: there is no medical situation and if your internship in the US creates some kind of humanitarian problem, it's a problem entirely of your making, so the solution to it is that you don't travel to the US. An emergency appointment would be denied.

Furthermore, your father should only re-apply if he has fixed the problems that caused the first application to be rejected. Don't think that applying again gives you another chance to get lucky: they'll see the first rejection and the first thing they'll check is whether the same reasons for rejection still apply.